# dyld: Library not loaded realm

Tags: ios, sdk, frameworks, realm

i added a framework that i developed in ios to the new project. I tried to make the app universal (one framework work both in device and simulator) according to this tutorial 
[create an ios universal framework](https://medium.com/@syshen/create-an-ios-universal-framework-148eb130a46c)
. When i run my demo project using this universal framework i get this errors

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Realm
```

Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DDF71B22-F535-43E5-B770-D3425419B108/DemoSDk2.app/Frameworks/#######.framework/#########
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DDF71B22-F535-43E5-B770-D3425419B108/DemoSDk2.app/Frameworks/########.framework/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DDF71B22-F535-43E5-B770-D3425419B108/DemoSDk2.app/Frameworks/##########.framework/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Realm'

both in device and simulator the demo app crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic frameworks are *by definition* not statically linked into binaries that link them.

This means dynamic frameworks must be shipped with the binaries that link them.

The typical way to do this for iOS apps is to have a build phase to copy the framework into your app bundle after compilation.

Comment: thank you please how i can  copy the framework into our app bundle after compilation.

Comment: Xcode's Build Phases section has a "Copy Files" template. You can use that.

Comment: i added realm using copy files template but i get usually the same error on runtime

Comment: this is the link to the copy files template http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/776326Capturedecran20170422a125321.png

Answer (score 0):

Due to restrictions by Apple for app store deployment it is not possible to dynamically link frameworks. This is an issue that is common amongst frameworks and not specific to Realm.

The following link is from Realm's GitHub discussion and explains in further detail and offers some work arounds (though none are particularly elegant.

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3051

Comment: i had others frameworks that i used in my framework like google maps and analytics but i get only this errors in runtime with realm !!!!!

Comment: Please file an issue with GitHub or follow up on the one that Adam mentioned and we'll do our best to further debug.